# custom rearranged menu with excerpt for selected children in sidebar.php

Tags: menus, loop, customization

I'm trying to make a custom index menu on the sidebar for an editorial multisite wordpress website. 
Suppose my pages are as follows:

```
Level 1
     Level 2
        Level 3
        Level 3
     Level 2
        Level 3
Level 1
Level 1
```

what I ultimately want to achieve is to display in the following manner for all the pages:

```
Level 1 (Title)
   Level 3 (Title)
     Level 2 (Title)
   Level 3 (Excerpt)
```

so it would look something like this:

```
Genre Name (Level 1 Title)
   Article Name (Level 3 Title)
     BY: Author (Level 2 Title)
   Excerpt of the article goes here...(Level 2 Excerpt)
```

I really would like to not use a plugin for this as I'd like to copy and paste for a new issue (subpage on the multisite) of the editorial site without much work on my client side. I'm hoping it can just be a php code I can plug in on sidebar.php unless of course you have something really good in mind. Thanks so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Your question is confusing. Is `Level 2` a child page of `Level 1` or do they have any other kind of relation between them?

Comment: thanks for your comment. sorry for the confusion. yes, they are children

Comment: Do they share any kind of information between them? Why Level 1 title a Genre Name, Whereas Level 2 is Author name? Why are you organizing your page this way? What will happen if a page doesn't have Level 2 and Level 3 sub-page? It will be better if you can explain what you are trying to achieve with this.